# Layout not working out as planned. Weights are set but going over edge of screen

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to create a new layout.  My last layout that I used was GridLayout and basically created a table with 3 columns and 8 rows.  With rowspan I was able to achieve the look that I wanted within Eclipse however, my screen is a little longer on my phone then Eclipse is and it shows that column 1 and 2 look good, but 3 was stretched to the right.

The new layouts looks like this:
[image]

** You can see the arrow on the right side is well over the edge of the screen and I don't know why.  I'm trying to create a layout that when used on different devices will scale appropriately.

The XML code is as follows:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightsum="1.0" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeft"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:src="@drawable/arrowleftoff" />

            <Space 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".34" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrowRight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:src="@drawable/arrowrightoff" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a lack of understanding how Eclipse works regarding layout.  First, the screen shown in the Eclipse visual layout editor is an "example" of what it would look like given the selected device at the top of the window (in my case Nexus S).

Second, the Layout I was using was not anchoring to certain elements or to the parent.  Therefore when the screen dimensions changed, the layout changed with it.

Conclusion:  I am now using and understanding RelativeLayout and it works wonders once you figure it out.

Here is a great resource which really helped me understand what was going on:  [Mobile Tuts Plus: Layout Basics](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)